# how to print output results in HDBSCAN

Tags: hdbscan

I have ASCII data and i need to cluster the data using HDBSCAN.
I got the lables but i don't know how to print the output cluster results i.e  unique and segregated results from hdbscan.

snippet:

```
import hdbscan
import numpy as np

datafile = "ascii.txt"

data = np.loadtxt(datafile, dtype = np.uint8)

clusterer = hdbscan.HDBSCAN(min_cluster_size = 20)

clusterer.fit(data)

print (np.unique(clusterer.labels_, return_counts = True))
```

Comment: Hello, please help!

Comment: I have printed the cluster points using labels_ , like   [-1  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9] but i would like to print the results into a text file for each cluster point [each cluster point containing the ASCII text]

Comment: please edit your question and add an example of how you want the output to look like.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Pandas to read the file and then print out the cluster labels along with the dataset you have as the input. Try something like:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("ascii.txt")
clusterer = hdbscan.HDBSCAN().fit_predict(df.ColumnName)
df_pd = pd.DataFrame({'Datapoints:' df.ColumnName, 'Cluster Labels:' clusterer)
```

Answer (score 0):

import hdbscan

import numpy as np

datafile = "ascii.txt"

data = np.loadtxt(datafile, dtype = np.uint8)

Modified_data=pd.DataFrame(data)

clusterer = hdbscan.HDBSCAN(min_cluster_size = 20)

clusterer.fit(Modified_data)

Modified_data['Clusters']=clusterer.labels_

Now Modified_data returns a pandas dataframe where you have a column named  "Clusters"  and cluster corresponding to each instance will be specified in the Clusters column.
You can manipulate this dataframe as per your requirement